How can I find the count of subarrays where product of that subarray has odd number of divisors?
I had this question in my test and I couldn't solve it.
any answer less than O(n2) time complexity is fine.
ex- array = [4,3,12] all sub-arrays = [4], [3], [12], [4,3], [3,12], [4,3,12] expected ans - [4], [4,3,12], [3,12]
1 <= array length <= 2*10^5
1 <= array[i] <= 200
I was doing it in the companies platform, so I don't have my code now but it wasn't passing all testcases and some of them were TLE.

you should provide an attempt you made in form a code snippet, so readers know you tried to solve it.

Since you potentially have a large array, but a small range of numbers (1..200), I'd start by factoring all the numbers from 1 to 200. Then just look up the factor count for each array element. Second, I'd probably only use a 0 or 1, to indicate even or odd count respectively. Then you're looking for subarrays with an odd number of 1's.

@JerryCoffin spot on in addition, to jerry's comment. you need to understand when a product has an odd number of divisors.

Why is [3,12] not considered part of the solution?  It's divisors are [1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18,36]. That's 9 divisors.

Third, I'd think a little about the numbers themselves. Factors normally come in pairs. So what sort of number would have an odd number of factors? (in fact, this probably obviates the need to factor the numbers from 1 to 200--with a little thought, you can generate those that have an odd number of factors without actually doing factoring). Looking, I suspect @DerekRoberts was probably hinting at the same thing I have in mind.

Precisely, I am more interested in finding a solution lesser than (2) . It seems nearly impossible.

Here's something I realized. In order to have an odd number of divisors, the product of the subarray would have to be a perfect square. (e.g. 1, 2, 4, 9, 16, 25, etc...) Not sure if that matters as the subarray products can be ginormous.

@selbie: That's where the prime factorizations of the factors come into use. To have a perfect square, every prime factor has to be raised to am even power. To use your example, 36 is 2^2 * 3^2. But for smaller numbers, you can just create a list of perfect squares up to, for example, all of them up to 2^32-1.

@DerekRoberts - I present on O(N) solution below in the second half of my updated answer.

I've provided an O(N) solution below. I tried to give credit to all the commenters that gave hints on how it could be done. Let me know if I missed something of I forgot to credit someone's contribution.

@selbie way to go... nicely done. Sighs, if only I had contributed, I would have my name in the sands of selbie's answer. sad much :( I would never have imagined a possible O(N)

I'm going to introduce a solution that does not require any multiplication of elements.
The solutions provided below were based on some ideas I had with hints from Jerry Coffin and @n. m. could be an AI
The trick is to recognize the following:

That the only integers that have an odd number of divisors are perfect squares (e.g. 2,4,9,16,25,36, etc...).

As Jerry called out in the comments, a perfect square has the property that every prime factor appears an even number of times. For example, 144 is 12x12, but it's also represented by 2² x 3².  29160000 is the square of 5400, but it's also expressed in primes as 2⁶ x 3⁶ x 5⁴).

Let's introduce the concept of the prime mask. The prime mask is a bitmask where each bit set represents an odd number of occurrences of a number in the prime factorization.  Given that the values in nums range from 1 to 200, this constrains the number of prime factors any value in that array can have. With only 43 prime numbers within 1 to 200, this makes it easy for coding.

For instance, 110 has prime factors of 2, 5, and 11, which correspond to  the first, third, and fifth primes. Thus, 110 can be represented by a prime mask of 00010101. Another example, 45, which is factored into primes as 3, 3, and 5, would have a "prime mask" of 00000100  because the number 3, appearing an even number of times, it cancels itself out in the bitmask.

The Prime Mask of AxB is the XOR of the two factors. That is PrimeMask(AxB) == PrimeMask(A) XOR PrimeMask(B)

Perfect squares, which are the only numbers that can have an odd number of divisors, will always have a prime mask of 0.


So now let's introduce a helper function that will return the prime mask of any value between 1..200.
uint64_t getPrimeMask(int value) {
    int primes[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199 };
    size_t count = sizeof(primes) / sizeof(*primes);
    uint64_t result = 0;

    if (value <= 1) {
        return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count && value > 1; i++) {
        uint64_t mask = 1ULL << i;
        while (value % primes[i] == 0) {
            result ^= mask;
            value = value / primes[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

First Solution: O(N²) implementation
Using the above helper function, we can introduce a solution function that finds all the subarrays with a product that has an odd number of divisors. The solution below works by first converting all the elements of nums into another array that holds the prime mask for each value in nums.
And then it does a nested for loop to XOR scan looking for all index ranges where the running XOR operation is 0.
uint64_t solve(const vector<int>& nums) {

    uint64_t result = 0;
    vector<uint64_t> maskTable(nums.size());

    // pre-compute the prime mask for all items in nums
    // maskTable[i] holds the primeMask for the value at nums[i]
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        maskTable[i] = getPrimeMask(nums[i]);
    }

    for (size_t start = 0; start < nums.size(); start++) {

        uint64_t primeMask = 0;

        for (size_t end = start; end < nums.size(); end++) {

            // xor all the prime masks from [start..end]

            primeMask ^= maskTable[end]; // xor in the next element in the sequence
            if (primeMask == 0) {
                result++;

                cout << "found match from indices " << start << " to " << end << ": [";
                for (size_t i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                    cout << ((i == start) ? "" : ", ") << nums[i];
                }
                cout << "]\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

Now apply that to the OP's example:
solve({4,3,12}

found match from indices 0 to 0: [4]
found match from indices 0 to 2: [4, 3, 12]
found match from indices 1 to 2: [3, 12]

I'll also note that OP didn't call out [3, 12] as an expected answer. But it absolutely is. 3x12 is 36. The factors of 36 are: {1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18,36}. That's nine factors and 36 == 6x6.
The above solution runs in runs in O(N²) time and uses O(1) storage.
Can we do better?
Better solution: O(N) implementation
It occurred to me with the hints provided by @n. m that there was a solution to go from O(N²) to O(N).  The hint is realizing that every iteration of the inner loop in the solution above is computing the same exact XOR operation on the same exact values sans the beginning values.  That is, the first loop XORs indices 0..N-1.  The next iteration is XORs indices 1..N-1.  The next does 2..N-1. Knowing that enables an optimization that relies on a hash table and a single loop.
The code below references the same getPrimeMask function discussed above.
uint64_t solve(const vector<int>& nums) {
    uint64_t result = 0;
    vector<uint64_t> maskTable(nums.size());
    unordered_map<uint64_t, vector<size_t>> lookupMap;
    uint64_t targetMask = 0;
    uint64_t runningPrimeMask = 0;

    // pre-compute the prime mask for all items in nums
    // maskTable[i] holds the primeMask for the value at nums[i]
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        maskTable[i] = getPrimeMask(nums[i]);
    }

    // build the lookup table that maps between a prime mask to a list of indices that hold that primeMask value
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        runningPrimeMask ^= maskTable[i];
        lookupMap[runningPrimeMask].push_back(i);
    }

    for (size_t start = 0; start < nums.size(); start++) {

        // lookup targetMask in the lookup table
        // each index in the vector represents an "end" index value
        // the subarray are all the elements between start and end

        auto key_value_pair = lookupMap.find(targetMask);

        if (key_value_pair != lookupMap.end()) {
            const auto& vec = key_value_pair->second;
            for (auto index : vec) {
                if (index >= start) {

                    result++;

                    cout << "found match from indices " << start << " to " << index << ": [";
                    for (size_t i = start; i <= index; i++) {
                        cout << ((i == start) ? "" : ", ") << nums[i];
                    }
                    cout << "]\n";
                }
            }
        }

        //  update targetMask to account for the starting position will change in the next loop iteration
        targetMask ^= maskTable[start];
    }
    return result;
}


I benchmarked the second solution on an array of 100000 integers in the range of 0-200. The code completes in just a handful of seconds.  (And instantly when the cout statements are removed). Whereas, the previous implementation would take a couple of minutes to complete.
The second solution runs in O(N) time and uses O(N) storage.

Create a prefix array of values in num xored (p[i] = nums[0]^...^nums[i]), then you only need to find the duplicates in the prefix array.

WAIT - O(N) solution incoming!

@selbie drums rolling...we have an answer O(n). how? I would never have imagined 0(N) solution. I did think deeply about the problem perhaps my error was trying to do the actual calculation this product *= arr[j] if (product > 1e12) { break;} rather using pure logic. I am impressed.

@n.m.couldbeanAI spot on! quite insightful.

Recall that one can compute the number of factors of a positive integer by finding the prime factorization, then taking the product of the multiplicities of each factor incremented by 1. Since the product of an even integer with another integer is always even, to make this product odd, all multiplicities must be even.
To start, create a dictionary that maps arrays of parities (0 for even, 1 for odd) of each prime factor to a count, initialized with the array of all 0s having a frequency of 1 (the point before the first array element). Since all array elements are between 1 and 200, we only need an array of size 200 for each state, which is O(1).
In taking a product of a subarray, we add the prime factor counts together. If we consider a prefix sum array, the frequency of each prime factor in the subarray between [l, r] is the difference in cumulative frequencies between r and l - 1.
Now, maintain a cumulative array of parities for each prime factor while iterating through the input. After updating the array of parities with the current element, we try the current index as the right endpoint r of a subarray and look for the number of indexes to be the matching l - 1. The cumulative parities of prime factors for this index should be the same as the current cumulative parities since subtracting two odd numbers or two even numbers produces an even number. As such, we access the dictionary with the current array of parities as the key and add the value to the result. Then, we increment the value for the current array of parities in the dictionary for later iterations.
This could be O(N) (expected) or O(N log N) depending on the dictionary implementation.

As both other answers indicate, a number has an odd number of factors if all of its prime factors have even multiplicities.
It's given that all the elements in the array are <= 200, and there are 46 primes < 200, so you can replace each element of the array with a bitmask, with a bit for each of those 46 primes, that is 1 if that prime factor has odd multiplicity in the number.
Now we just need to count all the subarrays that XOR to 0.
To do that we calculate the prefix XOR sum array, which replaces each element with the XOR of all previous elements.  Add an element at the end for the total sum.
Now we just need to count all pairs of matching prefix sums.
Count the frequencies of all the prefix sums.  Then, if a sum occurs n times, it represents n(n-1)/2 matching pairs.  Add the total number of matching pairs for all sums, and that is your answer.
